# is there a way to open notepad++ inside of my form?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am building a program that is pulling script from an object model. Right now I the script going into a text box and then on button click I am saving it to a temp file then opening that temp file with notepad++. It works and serves a purpose but I'd love to have notepad++ open inside of my form to make it more seamless.

Is there a way to do this?

This is my current code:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("c:temp\script.txt", textBox1.Text)
Process.Start("c:program files(86)\notepad++\notepad++.exe", "c:temp\script.txt")
```

any help or suggestions would be awesome!

Comment: I don't think so, Notepad++ doesn't come with an COM lib, or ActiveX control to use.  Try searching for code editor on CodePlex for alternatives that provide features similar to Notepad++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this?

You can't embed a program like `Notepad++` directly into your form.  However, you could use [ScintillaNET](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/) to add an editor directly within your program.  `ScintillaNET` is based on `Scintilla`, which is the underlying code used by Notepad++ and many other software products.

Comment: this sounds like it would be more ideal. do you know off hand if i can use ScintillaNET to make my textbox have the same vb editing style of notepad++?

Comment: @BSanders Yes, I believe this is possible.  You have to just set the configuration to use "vb" - see: http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=HowToSyntax&referringTitle=Documentation

Answer (score 0):

What About This!?

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class Form1
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
Private Shared Function MoveWindow(hWnd As IntPtr, X As Integer, Y As Integer, nWidth As Integer, nHeight As Integer, bRepaint As Boolean) As Boolean
End Function
<DllImport("user32.dll")>
Private Shared Function SetParent(hWndChild As IntPtr, hWndNewParent As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")>
Public Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer
End Function

Public ENotepad As New Process()

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.DoubleBuffered = True
    Notepad()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Closing(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing
    Try
        ENotepad.Kill()
    Catch
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Notepad()
    ENotepad.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" 'Application.StartupPath() & "\notepad++.exe"
    'ENotepad.StartInfo.Arguments = ""
    ENotepad.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    ENotepad.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    ENotepad.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    ENotepad.EnableRaisingEvents = True
    'AddHandler Notepad.OutputDataReceived, Sub(o, e) Debug.WriteLine(If(e.Data, "NULL"), "Notepad")
    'AddHandler Notepad.ErrorDataReceived, Sub(o, e) Debug.WriteLine(If(e.Data, "NULL"), "Notepad")
    'AddHandler Notepad.Exited, Sub(o, e) Debug.WriteLine("Exited", "Notepad")
    ENotepad.Start()
    Thread.Sleep(1000)
    Try
        SetParent(ENotepad.MainWindowHandle, Me.Handle)
        MoveWindow(ENotepad.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, 320, 180, True)
        'MoveWindow(ENotepad.MainWindowHandle, -5, -30, 320, 280, True)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.Text = "missed!"
    End Try

End Sub
End Class
```